# The function is not displayed, what to do

Tags: python

```
import random

hi=(
    "Привет",
    "Хай",
    "Hello",
    "Hi"
)

hi_hi=(["Приветствую!", "Привет!", "Добро пожаловать!", "Hi!"])

question=input("Сказать: ")

if question == hi:
    gen=random.choice(hi_hi)
    print(gen)
```

a random word from hi_hi should be returned but nothing happens
what is happening?

Comment: @nagyl doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if will never be true, you can check whether your input is in the list, but it won't be equal to the list.

1. `hi` should be a list, not a tuple.
2. `hi_hi` is really a list, not a tuple, but the brackets are misleading for some people.
3. You are matching your input to the elements of your list `hi`, not to the actual list.

import random

```
hi= [
    "Привет",
    "Хай",
    "Hello",
    "Hi"
]

hi_hi= ["Приветствую!", "Привет!", "Добро пожаловать!", "Hi!"]

question = input("Сказать: ")

if question in hi:
    gen=random.choice(hi_hi)
    print(gen)
```

Comment: `hi_hi` is not a tuple, but just a list. The parentheses around the square brackets are redundant and do not make `hi_hi` a tuple.

Comment: @blhsing just checked, you are right! It is misleading by the way.